# Use of embeddings to preserve order invariance

Tags: tensorflow, keras, embedding

I want to recommend an item complementary to a cart of items. So, naturally, I thought of using embeddings to represent items, and I came up to a layer of this kind in keras:

```
item_input = Input(shape=(MAX_CART_SIZE,), name="item_id")
item_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=NB_ITEMS+1, input_length=MAX_CART_SIZE, output_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE, mask_zero=True)
```

I used masking to handle the variable size of the carts. So, the dimensions of the output tensor of this layer is MAX_CART_SIZE x EMBEDDING_SIZE. It means that there are as many different embeddings as there are potential items. In other words, a item can be encoded a different way according to its position within the cart and that's an undesirable behavior... Though, it seems that most neural networks dealing with NLP data work this way, with embeddings not associated with words but with words/indices within a phrase.

So, what would be the correct way to preserve order invariance? In other words, I'd like the cart A,B,C be stricly equivalent to the carts C,B,A or B,A,C in terms of input representation and generated output.

Comment: do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

One way of having invariance will be done by using a Transformer architecture WITHOUT using positional embeddings. In this way, each item is encoded to an embedding, and because you do not have a positional embedding, the object embedding is the same even if it is one the first position or on the last one.

Moreover, the Transformer architecture is invariant to such positions as long as you avoid the positional embedding.

Comment: I've had a look at different code snippets implementing transformers with keras and they all use the embeddings at the start of the encoder. In what would permutation invariance be preserved?

Comment: in a transformer, as long as you do not use the positional embeddings, it does not care about the location. So, if you have embeddings for a word/object, but these embeddings only encode the information about the word/object without encoding information about its position, you will have permutation invariance. I do not know how keras does this, but I am sure you can get rid of the positional embedding if they really use them and just use the embeddings that encode information about your object/word.

Comment: Though, initiatives have been led to handle this invariance by permutation in transformers:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.00825.pdf